# Sometimes Widget not working

Tags: app-widgets

(Using Google Translator)

There is a phenomenon that the widget can not run under certain circumstances. Even Preview is invisible.

At first, it occurred at the terminal of Galaxy S9 or more, and now it happens irregularly. I've been wondering if it's a version issue, but it works fine on my phone and other test phones. It does not seem to be a version issue.

If you have any experience or have a solution, please help me.

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?hl=ko&account=7226599195870275510#AppDashboardPlace:p=com.guninnuri.guninday&appid=4974106757050605516

Comment: Are you the developer of this app?